# How to make plot with mean and standard deviation bands

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm looking for how to make a plot like this.
[image]

The center line in red is mean or average and the limits are standard deviations.

I made some plots and I can only do this:

[image]

Comment: There are two regions in the plot you're trying to recreate, an inner darker region and a wider lighter region. Are these confidence and prediction regions?  Any chance of a [mcve]?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg